# ZF2 Call to a member function prepare()

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have this message when trying to access after submit save on usereditform
error message:
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/CommunicationApp/module/Users/src/view/users/user-manager/edit.phtml on line 13
and here is my files
could any one told me what happend please>

UserManagerController.php

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


class UserManagerController extends AbstractActionController
{
public function indexAction(){
    //$form=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserManagerForm');
$userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array('users'=>$userTable->fetchAll()));
return $viewModel;
}

public function editAction(){
$userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
$user = $userTable->getUser($this->params()->fromRoute('id'));

//print_r($user);die;
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');
$form->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods());
$form->bind($user);
$form->setData($user);
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form'=>$form,'user_id' => $this->params()->fromRoute('id')));
return $viewModel;
}

public function processAction(){
$post = $this->request->getPost();
$userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
$user = $userTable->getUser($post->id);
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');
$form->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods());
$form->bind($user);
$form->setData($post);
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')->saveUser($user);

}
public function deleteAction(){
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')->deleteUser($this->params()->fromRoute('id'));
}
}
```

UserEditForm.php

```
<?php
// filename : module/Users/src/Users/Form/RegisterForm.php
namespace Users\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
class UserEditForm extends Form
{

public function __construct($name = null)
{
parent::__construct('UserEdit');
$this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
$this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');


$this->add(array('name' => 'id','attributes' => array('type' => 'text',),
'options' => array('label' => 'ID',),));



$this->add(array('name' => 'name','attributes' => array('type' => 'text',),
'options' => array('label' => 'Full Name',),));


$this->add(array('name' => 'email','attributes' => array('type' => 'email',),
'options' => array('label' => 'Email',),
    'filters' => array(array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
),));





$this->add(array('name' => 'submit','attributes' => array('type' => 'submit','value' => 'Save'),
));

}

}
```

edit.phtml

```
<section class="edit">
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php  if ($this->error): ?>
<p class="error">
There were one or more issues with your submission.
Please correct them as
indicated below.
</p>
<?php endif ?>
<?php
$form = $this->form;
//print_r($form);die;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
array('controller'=>'UserManager', 'action' => 'process')));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>



<dl class="zend_form">
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('id')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php

echo $this->formElement($form->get('id'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('id'));
?></dd>


<dl class="zend_form">
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php

echo $this->formElement($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('name'));
?></dd>



<dl class="zend_form">
<dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('email')); ?></dt>
<dd><?php

echo $this->formElement($form->get('email'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('email'));
?></dd>





<dd><?php
echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('submit'));
?></dd>
</dl>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
</section>
```

model/user.php

```
<?php
namespace Users\Model;
class User
{
public $id;
public $name;
public $email;
public $password;


public function setPassword($clear_password)
{
$this->password = md5($clear_password);
}
function exchangeArray($data)
{
$this->id = (isset($data['id'])) ?
$data['id'] : null;
$this->name = (isset($data['name'])) ?
$data['name'] : null;
$this->email = (isset($data['email'])) ?
$data['email'] : null;
if (isset($data["password"]))
{
$this->setPassword($data["password"]);
}
}
}
```

model/usertable.php

```
<?php
namespace Users\Model;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
class UserTable
{
protected $tableGateway;
public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
$this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}
public function saveUser(User $user)
{
$data = array(
'email' => $user->email,
'name' => $user->name,
'password' => $user->password,
);
$id = (int)$user->id;
if ($id == 0) {
$this->tableGateway->insert($data);
} else {
if ($this->getUser($id)) {
$this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
} else {
throw new \Exception('User ID does not exist');
}
}
}
public function getUser($id)
{
$id = (int) $id;
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
$row = $rowset->current();
if (!$row) {
throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
}

return $row;
}

public function fetchAll(){
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
return $resultSet;
}

public function getUserByEmail($userEmail){
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('email'=>$userEmail));
$row = $rowset->current();
if(!$row){
throw new \
Exception("Could not find row $userName");
}
return $row;
}

public function deleteUser($id)
{
$this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => $id));
}

}
```

and module.php

```
<?php
namespace Users;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

use Users\Model\User;
use Users\Model\UserTable;
use Users\Model\Uploads;
use Users\Model\UploadsTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;



class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{

public function getServiceConfig()
{
return array(
'abstract_factories' => array(),
'aliases' => array(),
'factories' => array(
// DB
'UserTable' => function($sm) {
$tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
$table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
return $table;
},
'UploadsTable' => function($sm) {
$tableGateway = $sm->get('UploadsTableGateway');
$table = new UploadsTable($tableGateway);
return $table;
},
'UserTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null,
$resultSetPrototype);
},
'UploadsTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Uploads());
return new TableGateway('uploads', $dbAdapter, null,
$resultSetPrototype);
},
// FORMS
'LoginForm' => function ($sm) {
$form = new \Users\Form\LoginForm();
$form->setInputFilter($sm->get('LoginFilter'));
return $form;
},
'UploadsManagerForm' => function ($sm) {
$form = new \Users\Form\UploadsManagerForm();
//$form->setInputFilter($sm->get('LoginFilter'));
return $form;
},
'RegisterForm' => function ($sm) {
$form = new \Users\Form\RegisterForm();
$form->setInputFilter($sm->get('RegisterFilter'));
return $form;
},
'UserEditForm' => function ($sm) {
$form = new \Users\Form\UserEditForm();
$form->setInputFilter($sm->get('UserEditFilter'));
return $form;
},
'UserManagerForm' => function ($sm) {
$form = new \Users\Form\UserManagerForm();
//$form->setInputFilter($sm->get('RegisterFilter'));
return $form;
},        
// FILTERS
'LoginFilter' => function ($sm) {
return new \Users\Form\LoginFilter();
},
'RegisterFilter' => function ($sm) {
return new \Users\Form\RegisterFilter();
},
'UserEditFilter' => function ($sm) {
return new \Users\Form\UserEditFilter();
},
'AuthenticationService' => function ($sm) {
return new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService();
},
'AuthenticationService' => function ($sm) {
return new \Users\Form\UserManager();
},

),
'invokables' => array('Users\Controller\UserManager' => 'Users\Controller\UserManagerController',
//'Users\Controller\UploadsManager' => 'Users\Controller\UploadsManagerController',
),
'services' => array(),
'shared' => array(),
);
}


    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
            // if we're in a namespace deeper than one level we need to fix the \ in the path
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
public function getFileUploadsLocation()
{
// Fetch Configuration from Module Config
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
return $config['module_config']['uploads_location'];
}
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        // You may not need to do this if you're doing it elsewhere in your
        // application
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thing you have to remove this line: $form = $this->form;, as your form is already on $form, and $this->form is empty or doesn't exist so you override your form with an empty value.

Comment: @sudo.ie
I tried to remove $form = $this->form, and nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is you are posting to processAction which doesn't return $form in the view model. Not sure why this is rendering the edit phtml but that is likely the issue.

Probably just want to add a redirect and flash message to the end of processAction

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage($this->translate('EDIT_SUCCESS'));
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users');
```

and another if the form fails validation.

I would probably post to the same action as well so that you can do all the validation stuff easily. But that's up to you... In editAction

```
     if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //saving and stuff
            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage($this->translate('EDIT_SUCCESS'));
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('users');
         } else {
             $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage($this->translate('EDIT_ERROR'));
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by returning the form at end of process action like this:

```
public function processAction(){
$post = $this->request->getPost();
$userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
$user = $userTable->getUser($post->id);
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')->saveUser($user);
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserEditForm');
$form->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods());
$form->bind($user);
$form->setData($post);
return $form;
}
```